# VMPlayer in ubuntu 15.10 cant compile several modules into the running kernel

Tags: upgrade, vmware, 15.10

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 15.10 I wasn't able to start vmplayer any more.

After executing this command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/vmware/lib/libglibmm-2.4.so.1/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I was able to fire up vmplayer but it keeps asking to compile several modules into the running kernel.

Message is:

> Before you can run VMware, several modules must be compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

After a quick lookup I found out that I had to install the linux-header files.

I executed:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

But this does not help. It keep said it needs to compile several modules into the running kernel. Anyone knows help?

Comment: What version of VMPlayer are you trying to use?

Comment: @CharlesGreen, I use VMware Player 7.1.2 build-2780323

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have also added

Run 
`sudo apt-get install build-essential` in your terminal.

These will be needed for all of the VMWare products

VMPlayer 7 has several known patches, which you can obtain and apply from [github](https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches/blob/master/README.md) - the process of applying the patches is pretty easy if you follow the directions closely.

There is a second, and I think probably superior alternative:  Download the current version of VMPlayer (version 12.01) from [vmware.com](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0)

Comment: Lookls like it works after the update to the new version. Thanks!